# Unable to restore (error 3456)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, recovery, restore

I have a situation that is not easy to figure out, and thought I'd ask on this forum if others might have suggestions.

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard SP3 on Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise.

A database needed some maintenance, and after the fact I needed to restore on another server. I have a full db backup done with COPY_ONLY plus a set of 4 tlog backups.

1. before starting, create tlogbackup1
2. change from `FULL` to `BULK_LOGGED` recovery model
3. add new filegroup
4. add file to newfilegroup
5. set newfilegroup to be default
6. select into table (on newfilegroup)
7. drop original table
8. delete original file
9. delete original filegroup
10. change name of new table to match original table
11. change file name of newfilegroup to match original filegroup
12. change file name in catalog to match original file name
13. change file name at OS level to match original file name
14. set default filegroup to be the original
15. bring db online
16. change from `BULK_LOGGED` to `FULL` recovery model
17. After all steps have completed, create tlogbackup2

The restore of all backups must use WITH MOVE, due to drive letter changes on the restore server.

Recovery steps:

```
RESTORE database SomeDB FROM DISK = 'D:\REPRO\SomeDB.bak'   
WITH 
MOVE 'SystemData' TO 'D:\SQLDATA\SomeDB.mdf'
,MOVE 'SystemDataPDS' TO 'D:\SqlData\SomeDB.ndf'
,MOVE 'SystemData_log' TO 'D:\SQLLogs\SomeDB.LDF'
,NORECOVERY
,stats = 1

RESTORE LOG SomeDB FROM DISK = 'D:\REPRO\tlogbackup1.trn'   
WITH 
MOVE 'SystemData' TO 'D:\SQLDATA\SomeDB.mdf'
,MOVE 'SystemDataPDS' TO 'D:\SqlData\SomeDB.ndf'
,MOVE 'SystemData_log' TO 'D:\SQLLogs\SomeDB.LDF'
,NORECOVERY
,stats = 1

RESTORE LOG SomeDB FROM DISK = 'D:\REPRO\tlogbackup2.trn'   
WITH 
MOVE 'SystemData' TO 'D:\SQLDATA\SomeDB.mdf'
,MOVE 'SystemDataPDS' TO 'D:\SqlData\SomeDB.ndf'
,MOVE 'SystemData_log' TO 'D:\SQLLogs\SomeDB.LDF'
,NORECOVERY
,stats = 1
```

The final tlog restore gets to 100% and then fails with error 3456:

> Processed 368 pages for database 'SomeDB', file 'SystemData' on file 1.
>
> Processed 7656520 pages for database 'SomeDB', file 'SystemDataPDS' on file 1.
>
> Processed 172430 pages for database 'SomeDB', file 'SystemData_log' on file 1.
>
> Msg 3456, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Could not redo log record (210388:123648:232), for transaction ID (0:1016710921), on page (4:8088), database 'SomeDB' (database ID 6). Page: LSN = (0:0:1), type = 11. Log: OpCode = 4, context 11, PrevPageLSN: (210388:122007:1). Restore from a backup of the database, or repair the database. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

Just to verify that the full db backup was ok, I restored it ran `CHECKDB`, and there were no errors.

All feedback welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Ned Otter

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why you think you have an unbroken log chain? The moment you flipped the database into BULK_LOGGED mode and started messing with the schema, all bets on having the log chain unbroken are off.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Thomas. 

I see now that the title of my post was incorrect. I don't need a point in time recovery, but a full restore to the end of the 4th tlog backup. So setting BULK_LOGGED should not have caused any issues with that. I don't see how what I did would have caused the 2nd tlog backup to fail - all commands were supported by SQL Server, and I ran the exact same steps (although not on the same data) on a smaller database, and was able to restore the 2nd tlog backup without issue.

Comment: The error looks like corruption. It is an internal error. Can you verify the integrity of all backup files? Are they with checksums?

Comment: I did verify that the full db backup had 0 errors by running CHECKDB. I will have to check to see if CHECKSUM was used.

Comment: I forgot to mention that applying the 2nd tlog backup caused a stack dump in the SQL error log.

Comment: Verified that each backup has CHECKSUM enabled.

Comment: If the backups have checksum enabled, then you should be using checksum for the restore as well. Page type 11 is a PFS page, which means you can't fix it, you can only do a full restore. Also, you don't say when the copy only backup was taken. Where was that backup in the time line?

Comment: Robert - thanks so much for your reply. 

Timeline:

Feb 6th, 9:45pm copy only full backup
Feb 7th, 2:11 pm, first tlog backup
Feb 7th, 2:47 pm, second  tlog backup

Anything further I might do or research to determine why this happened? As I mentioned above, I executed these steps without issue on a different db. 

My manager is thinking of opening a support case with MS, but I'm not sure much would be revealed by doing that. Corrupt is corrupt. The question is why.

Comment: I am unclear about what you mean in step 15? I assume the database was online while doing the previous steps.

Comment: @NedOtter: Can you share the .mdmp file that was written during the stack dump? Likely, if you stack dumped during an operation - all bets are off.

Comment: Thomas - the db was online until just prior to step 13. However it was in RESTRICTED_USER so that no app activity could occur. I will have to check with management to verify if it's ok to share the .mdmp. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to understanding why error 3456 would be thrown, we need to take a little step back and understand how SQL Server handles this corner of recovery.

When SQL Server is redoing an operation, and that redo is a page modification, it makes a quick check.  In the page header there is ultimately going to be a `PageLSN`, which is an indication of the last LSN that has modified that page, recorded by the page.  Think about it like this, the page keeps track of the last LSN that has made modifications to it.  This is the `PageLSN`.

Every time there is a logged page modification operation, that log record includes a few LSNs.  Namely, the log record's LSN (think... *Current LSN*), and then it has what's called the *Previous Page LSN* (`PrevPageLSN` going forward).  So when we modify a page, one of the pieces of data that is put into the log record is what the page indicates as being the *last LSN before you to have modified the page*.

Think about it like this...  Your car needs to have work done on it.  Mechanic John works on your car, and in the engine bay it has a little tag and Mechanic John writes "John worked on this car last".  Then the next time you take your car in to another shop, Mechanic Mark looks in the engine bay and sees that Mechanic John worked on this car last.  On his data sheet he writes this information.  Same idea with SQL Server.

This can be somewhat confusing, so take a look at this image below on sequential page modifications, and how the `PageLSN` and `PrevPageLSN` relate:

[image]

Let's loop back around, as this all comes into play when you need to *redo* an operation on a page (restores, recovery, HA, etc.).  When SQL Server needs to redo a page operation, it makes a sanity check to see if the `PageLSN` on the page matches the `PrevPageLSN` that the log record includes.  If that is not equal, then you will see error 3456 get thrown.

### Does *PageLSN* equal *PrevPageLSN*?  No???  Stop and raise error 3456...

Let's analyze your error message, which includes the how:

> Could not redo log record (210388:123648:232), for transaction ID (0:1016710921), on page (4:8088), database 'SomeDB' (database ID 6). **Page: LSN = (0:0:1)**, type = 11. Log: OpCode = 4, context 11, **PrevPageLSN: (210388:122007:1)**. Restore from a backup of the database, or repair the database. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

I have bold'd the two pieces of data that have an inequality causing the error.  You can see that our `PageLSN` is *0:0:1* (this was found in the page's header), and our `PrevPageLSN` is *210388:122007:1* (this was found in the data on the log record that was attempting to be redone).  These are obviously not equal, hence err3456.

So in order to find out the **why** of this event, would be to find out why there is a disparity here.  We really need to trace the lifecycle of page 4:8088 and see where the disconnect is.  Unfortunately without further information, or hands-on troubleshooting there isn't much else I can do besides give you the background of this recovery operation and what causes the error.

Comment: I know it's been awhile but still... good stuff, thanks for the thorough explanation!